# Apache Flink Integrating the BucketingSink with s3

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

Is it possible to use the BucketingSink that ships with Apache Flink to write data into s3?

I have tried several combinations of the URL but I can't seem to get anywhere with s3

e.g. s3://bucket/path/to/folder

I can write to hdfs when deployed to EMR 5.4.0 but not s3.

The documentation doesn't mention S3 as a potential integration but I am assuming it is supported natively.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html

I get the following error if I use the s3a:// url format

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams.setSoKeepalive(Lorg/apache/http/params/HttpParams;Z)V
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:96)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:187)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:136)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:394)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:374)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:356)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:235)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2717)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2751)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2733)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:377)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:417)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:351)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.util.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.util.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:106)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:225)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:666)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:654)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:257)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:655)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMR does things which aren't 10% compatible with the S3A client from ASF Hadoop. Stick to Amaon's s3:// URLs: it's the one they support